# Why is the equation object empty in json when returned from the google doc api?

Tags: node.js, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to fetch the google doc content using the [google doc api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) but I see that the json returned from the google doc api is missing eqaution information.

Example content :-
[google doc excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEszu.png)
Example request :-

```
const baseUrl = `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${doc_id}`
    const response = await googleReq(baseUrl, ctx.accessToken).then(res => {
        let data = res.json()
        return data
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

const googleReq = (url, token) => {
    if (!token) return new Error("No accessToken")
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
}

example response :- 
...
{
   "startIndex": 321,
   "endIndex": 330,
   "equation": {}
}
...
```

As you can see the equation block is not returning anything. I am not sure why it would be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, at present, you can not get equation information from the Google Docs API.*

#### More Information:

As per the [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents?authuser=2#Equation), the `equation` block returned by the API should contain:

- `suggestedInsertionIds[]`
- `suggestedDeletionIds[]`

These IDs would be alphanumeric strings which indicate the suggestions that an editor would have inserted or deleted.

This block will not contain any equation text or other related info.

#### The Only Way:

At present, there is only one to get the equation text programmatically, and that is using Google Apps Script methods.

An example script to do this would be:

```
// Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function getEquations() {

  const searchElementType = DocumentApp.ElementType.EQUATION
  const documentBody = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
  const searchResult = null

  while (searchResult = documentBody.findElement(searchElementType,searchResult)) {
    let par = searchResult.getElement().asEquation()
    console.log("Search Result : " + par.getText())
  }
}
```

As a workaround, you could deploy this as a web app which serves the equation text as JSON content, and then use the fetch API in JavaScript to get this data rather than using the Google Docs API directly.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Google  Docs component](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211190), with the `Feature Request` template.

#### References:

- [REST Resource: documents | Google Docs API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents)
- [Enum ElementType | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type)
- [Class DocumentApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)
- [Class ContainerElement | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element)

#### References for Web App-based Workround:

- [Web Apps | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Content Service | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)

  - [Serving JSON from scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_json_from_scripts)
- [Class ContentService | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)